# docker nginx and letencrypt certificate handling not trusted

Tags: docker, nginx, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to host an api and a website using docker. I want the certificates to be auto renewed. I can see that my certificates are generated and they look all good. They appear in the /etc/nginx/certs folder. The website is running and i can go to my healthcheck endpoint in the api and it all works fine. It just that the certificates doesn't seem to be loaded the way they should. When i go to my website it says the website is not trusted.

```
`version: '3'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:1.2.2
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /etc/nginx/certs
      - /etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    environment:
      - DEFAULT_HOST=default.local
    networks:
      - app-network
    restart: always

  nginx-letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: nginx-letsencrypt
    volumes:
      - /etc/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    volumes_from:
      - nginx-proxy
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy
    environment:
      #- ACME_CA_URI=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory # remove when live
      - NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER=nginx-proxy
      - DEFAULT_EMAIL=email@gmail.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_RENEWAL_DAYS=90
    restart: always

  appenings-api:
    image: sjc.vultrcr.com/myregistery/website-api
    container_name: website-api
    expose:
      - "3000"
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=api.website.se
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=api.website.se
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=email@gmail.com
    networks:
      - app-network
    restart: always

  appenings-web:
    image: sjc.vultrcr.com/myregistry/website-api
    container_name: website-web
    expose:
      - "80"
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=website.se
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=website.se
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=email@gmail.com
    networks:
      - app-network
    restart: always

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge`
```

I have tried a lot of different variations of this and asked chatgpt a lot about it.